# Can you turn off yellow warnings in React Native Debugger?

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

I'm using React Native Debugger 0.13.0. Is it possible to turn off the yellow warning messages? I know how to do it in React Native itself, but not in the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on default levels and clear warnings selection .

[image]